# How to force an attribute to be present only if another one is true?

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm trying to validate a simple object using Joi. The schema i defined is the following:

```
const singleReq = Joi.object({  
    subscribing: Joi.boolean(),  
    duration: Joi.number().integer().positive(),
});
```

I would like `duration` to be present (not null) only when `subscribing` is true. I'm trying to do it with asserts but i can't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like below:

```
const singleReq = Joi.object({  
  subscribing: Joi.boolean(),  
  duration: Joi.number()
  .when('subscribing', { is: true, then: Joi.integer().positive().required() })
});
```

If you want change of type, you could also try to use alternatives like the below example:

```
const schema = {
  a: Joi.alternatives().when('b', { is: 5, then: Joi.string(), otherwise: Joi.number() }),
  b: Joi.any()
};
```

[references](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.6.0/API.md#alternativeswhenref-options)

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what i needed!